# Is my server time incorrect?

Tags: php, datetime, unix-timestamp

Here's what my server says:

```
date('c') = 2012-08-09T22:11:13-04:00
time() = 1344564673
```

Within 10 seconds, here's what http://www.unixtimestamp.com says:

```
THE CURRENT UNIX TIME STAMP

1344568431 EST (-5 GMT + DST when appropriate)
1344564831 UTC (GMT)

...seconds since Jan 01 1970. 
This translates to current server time of 08/09/2012 @ 10:13pm in EST.
```

... and when I type **my server's** time stamp of `1344564673` into unixtimestamp's converter I get:

```
TIME STAMP: 1344564673
DATE (M/D/Y @ h:m:s): 08 / 09 / 12 @ 9:11:13pm EST
```

... My server's off by almost an hour, right? Or am I missing something? (I don't care if it's off by a few minutes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your time appears correct (within a few minutes).

It appears that `unixtimestamp.com` isn't taking DST into effect, which it is right now in EST.  That's why their time is off by an hour from what you get from PHP.

Instead try [epochconverter.com](http://www.epochconverter.com/) which does handle DST.

Just FYI in case you didn't already know: `time()` always returns timestamps in UTC.  When you output them in PHP using `date()`, the output is reflected in the timezone currently set in PHP.  This can be set in `php.ini` using the `date.timezone` setting, and you can switch it at runtime using [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/date_default_timezone_set).

Hope that helps.